# Center images in a Grid (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a one page site for a little consulting team, and in the section were the team appears, I can't make to align the justified content with an image that I would like to add in top of the text.

Here is what I have

HTML

```
<section>
    <h2 class="altura">Equipo</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="teamg">
            <img class="fotoequipo" src="img/brad1.jpg">
            <h3>Ps. Brad Pitt</h3>
            <h4>Associate</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="teamg2">
            <img class ="fotoequipo1" src="img/jen1.jpg">
            <h3>Ps. Jennifer Aniston</h3>
            <h4>Associate</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.altura {
    margin: 3vw 20vw 3vw 20vw;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
}

.teamg {
    grid-column-start: 2;
}

.teamg img {
    align-content: center;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #2b2c35;
}

.fotoequipo {
    align-items: center;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #2b2c35;
}

.teamg2 {
    grid-column-start: 4;
}

.teamg2 img {
    align-content: center;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #2b2c35;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you're asking. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: add the desired result you are looking for so we can help you more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to center the text like this:

```
.teamg {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

and this:

```
.teamg2 {
   grid-column-start: 4;
   text-align: center;
}
```

[Here is a link of the output](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-sound-z8bxu)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem :D

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you are not happy with the alignment of the text beneath the images - because it 'seems' un-centered.

It's actually perfectly centered, but the text is right aligned - and the image is full width.

Here's a tidied up version of your css/html - maybe this will help.

```css
.altura {
    margin: 3vw 20vw 3vw 20vw;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
}

.teamg {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px grey;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.teamg img {
    align-content: center;
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #2b2c35;
}

.column4 {
    grid-column-start: 4;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <h2 class="altura">Equipo</h2>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="teamg">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180">
            <h3>Ps. Brad Pitt</h3>
            <h4>Associate</h4>
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="teamg column4">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180">
            <h3>Ps. Jennifer Aniston</h3>
            <h4>Associate</h4>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I never tought that the text was not aligned, now I will be more aware of this :)

Answer (score -2):

```
<center>
    <img src="path/to/your/image/here"/>
</center>
<style>
img{
    object-fit:center;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please first Run your Code And Then Answer